# Intent to pass info to new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
public void onClick(View v) {
String value="Pass this";
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoadActivity.class);
i.putExtra("KEY",value);
startActivity(i);
```

I have been using this way of sending info to new activity and wanted to know if I can use this same way but not go to new activity just save the `String` in case I wanted to save multiple things in one activity then go to the next.

Comment: Your question is not clear? Do you mean to ask that you can save things in LoadActivity and then load new activity from there?

Comment: Sorry. I can already save things and load them. I wanted to know if I can save things without jumping to the nextActivity

Answer (score 0):

Once any activity is closed the data can only come back in one of the 2 ways.

If you pass a Bundle to the onSaveInstanceState() method or if you use SharedPreferences.

The onSaveInstanceState() method is usually used to store information while the device configuration changes, for instance: the orientation of the device.

Use SharedPreferences if you want data to be persistent across the entire app. That data can then be accessed from whatever activity you're in.

[This Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) from Google explains SharedPreferences in details.It's quite easy to implement too compared to onSaveInstanceState() because you don't have to worry about the activity lifecycle.